# Result set column has value BLOB

Tags: mysql, blob

I'm concatenating some 5 fields from a table. But the result set for that concatenated field is showing BLOB. Pls. advise me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance, Krishna!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CONVERT or CAST function with character name to get a string, e.g. -

```
SELECT CONVERT(column_name USING latin1) FROM table_name;
```

[CONVERT/CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) functions.

Comment: Welcome;) You have got BLOB because you have concantenated columns of different types.